# Use rules from weka inside Java code

Tags: java, classification, weka

I'm using rules generated by classifiers from weka. These rules are generated in one String by Weka and in each different case of rules I have to implement each one (i.e manually, in Java). I think that maybe there is a better way to do this process, maybe using an API.

One way that I could do it is treat the String that is generated by the classifier that represents the rules (class ClassifierTree). But I think that could have some easiest way.

Anyone could help me?

Regards,

Bruno Moreno

Comment: [Use WEKA with Java](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code). Second google result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your classifier [supports it](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/Sourcable.html), you may get java code for trained classifier. Look to [following answer option three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319279/how-to-apply-classifier-in-wekas-explorer/10537185#10537185). Following excerpt is from [Weka Wiki Generating source code from WEKA classes](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Generating+source+code+from+WEKA+classes):

```
All classifiers implementing the weka.classifiers.Sourcable interface 
can turn their model into Java source code 
(check the Javadoc of this interface for all the classifiers implementing it).
```

Comment: It is exactaly what I want, @atilla-ozgur, I try do it. Thank you so much!